# My Ethernet card doesn't connect to my router, but does to my laptop?

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, ethernet

My desktop stopped connecting to the internet today. It has an Ethernet adapter, which is built into the motherboard, and no Wi-Fi functionality.

I started by ruling out faulty cables, by testing the Ethernet connection with my laptop (with wi-fi turned off entirely), which worked properly.

I reset the router to default settings, with assistance from my ISP, Bell, to no avail.
Next, I tried to use `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh int ip reset`, to no avail.

In frustration, I tried to bridge a connection from my laptop's wi-fi through its Ethernet adapter to my desktop. Surprisingly, this worked, and I can navigate properly on the desktop and laptop at the same time.

I tried to reinstall the driver for the desktop's Ethernet adapter. It continued not to work without using the bridged connection through the laptop, both with the default driver and the one provided by Windows' automatic update.

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue, and I haven't found any other suggested steps in my searches.

In short, my desktop's Ethernet adapter does not work when connected directly to router, but works when connected to laptop using a bridged connection.

Comment: @Scott I've attempted to clarify it a bit in the question body. No wi-fi on the desktop at all, only Ethernet. The desktop fails to connect to the router. The laptop connects to the router successfully both through wi-fi and through Ethernet. The desktop connects to the laptop succesfully, to use its bridged connection. Intent is to be able to connect desktop to router without the laptop having to be involved.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've ordered a network card to try and rule out a hardware issue, but I still want to fix this if possible, since it does allow me to access the internet in this weird way.

Comment: What do the link and activity lights (at the RJ45 connector) do when you connect a cable between the desktop and router?  How does the desktop get its IP address when you connect it to the laptop?

Comment: NIC can connect to laptop and cannot connect to router? This looks like there is some (strange) problems with link speed and MDI/MDIx autodetection. Try: 1) disable MDI/MDIx autodetection on both NIC and (if possible) router port 2) use fixed link speed (try each possible variant) on both NIC and (if possible) router port 3) use (8-wire) cross-over cable.

Comment: I have to agree with akina, try another router port. It's not at all uncommon for them to fail.